# React: Can't fetch local file from src folder, but can from public

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch a local file "file.html" and set it into a state as a string. The program is not able to locate my file in the src folder, but instead in the public. How to do it in the src.

```
const [html, setHTML] = useState("");

async function getProjectCode() {
    const file = "file.html"
    await fetch(file)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
        setHTML(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static import of html files you can use with webpack [HTML webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/).
If they are dynamic content (ajax) you have to move the files from the src folder to the public.